# How to define `bind` for a type with record syntax in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads

I'm completely stuck when solving a Monad assignment in Haskell course. There is a sample data type I want to define Monad-specific functions for:

```
data MyMonad a = MyMonad { func :: String -> a }

instance Functor MyMonad where
    fmap f (MyMonad x) = MyMonad (\a -> f (x a))   

instance Applicative MyMonad where
    pure x = MyMonad (\a -> x)
    (MyMonad f) <*> (MyMonad g) = MyMonad (\a -> (f a)(g a))

instance Monad MyMonad where
    return x = MyMonad (\a -> x)
    MyMonad x >>= f = f (\a -> x a) --my wrong definition
```

Once Functor and Applicative instances declared, I'm trying to do the same for Monad, but...I'm not a little bit closer to understand how to fit a record syntax `func` into that `f` function. So far I see `bind` as a function to take an `x` of `MyMonad` before mapping it over `f`. It's just a cricial feature of any Monad - enable putting some values from one data type context to another one - as far as I realize that. To be honest, I'm aware of `bind` definitions in Monad instances for `[a], Maybe` and several other everpresent types. Yes, I see clearly what's a common purpose the Monad class serves for. However, I need to get any suggestion in this specific case just to enhance my understanding about the way to deal with something like records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `x` in `MyMonad x` has as type `String -> a`, whereas `f` has as type `a -> MyMonad b`, we thus should return a `MyMonad b` (that wraps a function `String -> b)`.

We thus should construct a function that maps a `s :: String` to a `b`. We can do that by first passing that `s` to the `x` function, and retrieve a value of type `a`. Next we can call `f` with `a` as that parameter, ands retrieve a `MyMonad g`. We can then apply that `s` to `g`.

We can thus implement the `Monad` instance as:

```
instance Monad MyMonad where
    return x = MyMonad (\a -> x)
    MyMonad x >>= f = MyMonad (\s -> let MyMonad g = f (x s) in g s)
```

since you defined a "getter" `func :: MyMonad a -> a -> String`, we can make use of that getter instead of using a `let … in …` expression to "unwrap" the value out of the `MyMonad` data constructor:

```
instance Monad MyMonad where
    return x = MyMonad (\a -> x)
    MyMonad x >>= f = MyMonad (\s -> func (f (x s)) s)
```

Comment: I've tried to map `>>=` type definition into this real case, but (as I knew after your answer) I was very, very far...Positively, now it stands clear, including some particularities which wondered me. It's appreciable help, thank you a lot.